# Big O help, I have a basic idea

Tags: java, recursion, big-o

I'm looking at working out the Big O time complexity of the below code. What the code does is a recursive call to solve which attempts to perform `empty` operations until all stones are in a single cup.

What I've got so far, is that the recursive calls are calling `solve` from limit until limit is now 1. So big O is (limit, limit-1, limit-2 all the way until limit = 1).

Would this recursive function be O(n)?

```
public void solve(Cups cups, int limit, boolean debug){
        String prevState = cups.toString();
        for(int i = 0; i < cups.size(); i++){ //for every cup
          Cups emptyCups = cups.empty(i); //make a new instance and empty the contents of cup
          emptyCups.stateList.addAll(cups.stateList);
          emptyCups.stateList.add(prevState); //add previous state to stateList arraylist
          emptyCups.moveList.addAll(cups.moveList); //add all moves to arraylist
          emptyCups.moveList.add(i); //add i position to move list
          if(debug = true){
            System.err.println(prevState + " empty-cup:"+ i +
                               ", limit:" + limit + " => " + emptyCups);
          }
          if(emptyCups.size() == 1){ //base case
            StringBuilder solution = new StringBuilder("moves:" + emptyCups.moveList);
            solution.append(" cups:");
            for(int j = 0; j < emptyCups.stateList.size(); j++){
              solution.append(emptyCups.stateList.get(j) + " ");
            }
            solution.append(emptyCups.toString());
            System.out.println(solution);
            unsolvable = false;
          } else if(limit > 1){
            solve(emptyCups, limit - 1, debug);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that size is a constant no matter how many cups you have.

This code would be (O(n)), with n being the value of limit.  This is because this method runs once additional time each time increase is increased by 1.  There is no increase in work that I can see within the method if limit is high compared to when it is low.  There are a lot of things that need to be done each time the method is called, but because it is a finite amount of "stuff" each time, it does not affect the complexity.